# uninitialized constant ActiveSupport::Concern (NameError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, activesupport

I'm using rbenv, Bundler 1.0.21, rubygems 1.8.1, Ruby v1.8.7, rails 2.3.15 and rails 3.0.18. I'm in the process of migrating my rails app from 2.3.15 to rails 3.0.18. When I switch between these versions I run "bundle install" to point to the correct set of gems. And this has worked fine until I switched from rails 3.0.18 back to 2.3.15 and ran a spec and I get:

```
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/1.8.7-p357/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.15/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:466:in 
`load_missing_constant': uninitialized constant ActiveSupport::Concern (NameError)
from /Users/me/.rbenv/versions/1.8.7-p357/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.15/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:106:in `const_missing'
from /Users/me/Code/repos/microplace/vendor/plugins/verification/lib/action_controller/verification.rb:3
from /Users/me/.rbenv/versions/1.8.7-p357/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/base.rb:1418
from /Users/me/.rbenv/versions/1.8.7-p357/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/base.rb:1416:in `class_eval'
from /Users/me/.rbenv/versions/1.8.7-p357/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/base.rb:1416
from /Users/me/Code/repos/microplace/config/environments/development.rb:12:in `load_environment'
from /Users/me/.rbenv/versions/1.8.7-p357/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.15/lib/initializer.rb:386:in `load_environment'
from /Users/me/.rbenv/versions/1.8.7-p357/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.15/lib/active_support/core_ext/kernel/reporting.rb:11:in `silence_warnings'
from /Users/me/.rbenv/versions/1.8.7-p357/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.15/lib/initializer.rb:379:in `load_environment'
from /Users/me/.rbenv/versions/1.8.7-p357/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.15/lib/initializer.rb:137:in `process'
from /Users/me/.rbenv/versions/1.8.7-p357/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.15/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `send'
from /Users/me/.rbenv/versions/1.8.7-p357/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.15/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `run'
from /Users/me/Dropbox/Code/repos/microplace/config/environment.rb:15
from /Users/me/.rbenv/versions/1.8.7-p357/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.15/lib/commands/runner.rb:39:in `require'
from /Users/me/.rbenv/versions/1.8.7-p357/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.15/lib/commands/runner.rb:39
from script/runner:3:in `require'
from script/runner:3
```

Thinking that maybe there was some incompatibility issues with rubygems, I tried downgrading to versions 1.3.4, 1.4.5, and 1.5.0, with the same result.

When I run gem which rails, it gave:

```
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/1.8.7-p357/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.18/lib/rails.rb
```

So, I uninstalled railties. With the same result.

gem which activesupport returns:

```
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/1.8.7-p357/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.15/lib/activesupport.rb
```

I also tried deleting all of the gems in my .rbenv/versions/1.8.7-p357/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/ directory using this script: https://gist.github.com/IanVaughan/2902499 and reinstalled using bundle install, with the same result.

Here's my Gemfile

```
source :gemcutter
gem "rails", "2.3.15"
gem 'activesupport', '2.3.15'
gem "mysql"
gem "rake", "0.9.2"
gem "rack", "1.1.3"
gem "mongrel"

# bundler requires these gems in all environments
gem "nokogiri"
gem "money", "5.0.0"
gem "memcache-client"
gem "oauth"
gem "fastercsv"
gem "pdf-writer"
gem "json", "1.5.3"
gem "rmagick", :require => 'RMagick'
gem "twitter"
gem "will_paginate", "2.3.15"
gem "image_science"
gem "RubyInline"
gem "sentry"
gem "netaddr"
gem "hashie"
gem "activemerchant", "~>1.24.0"
gem "httparty"
gem "httmultiparty"
gem "ruby-hmac"
gem "mogli"
gem "SystemTimer"
gem "net-sftp"
gem "roxml"
gem "rdoc"
gem "omniauth-salesforce"
gem "xml-simple"
gem "rcov"
gem "ZenTest", "4.8.3"

group :development do
  # bundler requires these gems in development
  # gem "rails-footnotes"
end

group :test do
  # bundler requires these gems while running tests
  gem "rdoc"
  gem "rcov"
  gem "factory_girl", '2.6.4'
  gem "mocha", '< 0.13.0', :require => false
  gem "timecop"
  gem "rspec", '~> 1.3.0'
  gem "rspec-rails", '~> 1.3.4'
  gem "cucumber-rails", '~> 0.3.2'
  gem "database_cleaner", '~> 0.5.0'
  gem "webrat", '~> 0.7.0'
  gem "redgreen"
  gem "launchy"
  gem 'shoulda', :require => false
end

group :development, :test do
  gem "ruby-debug"
  #gem "ruby-debug-ide"
end

group :production, :salesforce_staging do
  gem "mongrel_cluster"
  gem "daemons"
end
```

Gemfile.lock:

```
GEM
  remote: http://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    RubyInline (3.12.1)
      ZenTest (~> 4.3)
    SystemTimer (1.2.3)
    ZenTest (4.8.3)
    actionmailer (2.3.15)
      actionpack (= 2.3.15)
    actionpack (2.3.15)
      activesupport (= 2.3.15)
      rack (~> 1.1.3)
    active_utils (1.0.5)
      activesupport (>= 2.3.11)
      i18n
    activemerchant (1.24.0)
      active_utils (>= 1.0.2)
      activesupport (>= 2.3.11)
      builder (>= 2.0.0)
      i18n
      json (>= 1.5.1)
      money
      nokogiri
    activerecord (2.3.15)
      activesupport (= 2.3.15)
    activeresource (2.3.15)
      activesupport (= 2.3.15)
    activesupport (2.3.15)
    addressable (2.3.3)
    builder (3.2.0)
    cgi_multipart_eof_fix (2.5.0)
    color (1.4.1)
    columnize (0.3.6)
    cucumber (1.2.1)
      builder (>= 2.1.2)
      diff-lcs (>= 1.1.3)
      gherkin (~> 2.11.0)
      json (>= 1.4.6)
    cucumber-rails (0.3.2)
      cucumber (>= 0.8.0)
    daemons (1.1.9)
    database_cleaner (0.5.2)
    diff-lcs (1.2.1)
    factory_girl (2.6.4)
      activesupport (>= 2.3.9)
    faraday (0.8.6)
      multipart-post (~> 1.1)
    fastercsv (1.5.5)
    fastthread (1.0.7)
    gem_plugin (0.2.3)
    gherkin (2.11.5)
      json (>= 1.4.6)
    hashie (1.2.0)
    httmultiparty (0.3.8)
      httparty (>= 0.7.3)
      multipart-post
    httparty (0.10.2)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
      multi_xml (>= 0.5.2)
    httpauth (0.2.0)
    i18n (0.6.4)
    image_science (1.2.4)
      RubyInline (~> 3.9)
    json (1.5.3)
    launchy (2.2.0)
      addressable (~> 2.3)
    linecache (0.46)
      rbx-require-relative (> 0.0.4)
    memcache-client (1.8.5)
    metaclass (0.0.1)
    mocha (0.12.10)
      metaclass (~> 0.0.1)
    mogli (0.0.28)
      httparty (>= 0.4.3)
    money (5.0.0)
      i18n (~> 0.4)
      json
    mongrel (1.1.5)
      cgi_multipart_eof_fix (>= 2.4)
      daemons (>= 1.0.3)
      fastthread (>= 1.0.1)
      gem_plugin (>= 0.2.3)
    mongrel_cluster (1.0.5)
      gem_plugin (>= 0.2.3)
      mongrel (>= 1.0.2)
    multi_json (1.6.1)
    multi_xml (0.5.3)
    multipart-post (1.2.0)
    mysql (2.9.1)
    net-sftp (2.1.1)
      net-ssh (>= 2.6.5)
    net-ssh (2.6.6)
    netaddr (1.5.0)
    nokogiri (1.5.6)
    oauth (0.4.7)
    oauth2 (0.6.1)
      faraday (~> 0.7)
      httpauth (~> 0.1)
      multi_json (~> 1.3)
    omniauth (1.1.3)
      hashie (~> 1.2)
      rack
    omniauth-oauth2 (1.0.2)
      oauth2 (~> 0.6.0)
      omniauth (~> 1.0)
    omniauth-salesforce (1.0.3)
      omniauth (~> 1.0)
      omniauth-oauth2 (~> 1.0)
    pdf-writer (1.1.8)
      color (>= 1.4.0)
      transaction-simple (~> 1.3)
    rack (1.1.3)
    rack-test (0.6.2)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    rails (2.3.15)
      actionmailer (= 2.3.15)
      actionpack (= 2.3.15)
      activerecord (= 2.3.15)
      activeresource (= 2.3.15)
      activesupport (= 2.3.15)
      rake (>= 0.8.3)
    rake (0.9.2)
    rbx-require-relative (0.0.9)
    rcov (1.0.0)
    rdoc (4.0.0)
      json (~> 1.4)
    redgreen (1.2.2)
    rmagick (2.13.2)
    roxml (3.3.1)
      activesupport (>= 2.3.0)
      nokogiri (>= 1.3.3)
    rspec (1.3.2)
    rspec-rails (1.3.4)
      rack (>= 1.0.0)
      rspec (~> 1.3.1)
    ruby-debug (0.10.4)
      columnize (>= 0.1)
      ruby-debug-base (~> 0.10.4.0)
    ruby-debug-base (0.10.4)
      linecache (>= 0.3)
    ruby-hmac (0.4.0)
    sentry (0.5.3)
    shoulda (3.0.1)
      shoulda-context (~> 1.0.0)
      shoulda-matchers (~> 1.0.0)
    shoulda-context (1.0.2)
    shoulda-matchers (1.0.0)
    simple_oauth (0.2.0)
    timecop (0.6.0)
    transaction-simple (1.4.0.2)
    twitter (4.6.0)
      faraday (~> 0.8, < 0.10)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
      simple_oauth (~> 0.2)
    webrat (0.7.3)
      nokogiri (>= 1.2.0)
      rack (>= 1.0)
      rack-test (>= 0.5.3)
    will_paginate (2.3.15)
    xml-simple (1.1.2)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  RubyInline
  SystemTimer
  ZenTest (= 4.8.3)
  activemerchant (~> 1.24.0)
  activesupport (= 2.3.15)
  cucumber-rails (~> 0.3.2)
  daemons
  database_cleaner (~> 0.5.0)
  factory_girl (= 2.6.4)
  fastercsv
  hashie
  httmultiparty
  httparty
  image_science
  json (= 1.5.3)
  launchy
  memcache-client
  mocha (< 0.13.0)
  mogli
  money (= 5.0.0)
  mongrel
  mongrel_cluster
  mysql
  net-sftp
  netaddr
  nokogiri
  oauth
  omniauth-salesforce
  pdf-writer
  rack (= 1.1.3)
  rails (= 2.3.15)
  rake (= 0.9.2)
  rcov
  rdoc
  redgreen
  rmagick
  roxml
  rspec (~> 1.3.0)
  rspec-rails (~> 1.3.4)
  ruby-debug
  ruby-hmac
  sentry
  shoulda
  timecop
  twitter
  webrat (~> 0.7.0)
  will_paginate (= 2.3.15)
  xml-simple
```

I'm stumped. Thanks in advance, for any ideas of how I can get past this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this issue was caused by a Rails 3 plugin I had installed, but not committed to git. So when I switched back to my Rails 2.3.15 branch, the plugin remained. (the verification plugin)

I discovered this by simply doing a recursive grep for "ActiveSupport::Concern" in my project root. I also did this in my

```
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/1.8.7-p357/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems
```

directory, and discovered that the cucumber-rails gem instantiated ActiveSupport::Concern. From there, I loosened the versioning in the Gemfile and re-ran bundle install. This downgraded the cucumber-rails version. I don't know if cucumber-rails was also causing the error, but I suspect so, given that it was calling ActiveSupport::Concern.

Hope this helps someone else in the future!